# how to remove extra spaces in grid?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I was trying to make similar to this grid but which I had made its width are not flexible.

[image]

I used `display:flex` in .grid-Items but it changed the structure as compared to above figure. and same error `flex-shrink` showing. they are not working. so how to make structure like above figure grid?

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div className="row5">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-item">
            
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" alt="searchdoctor" />
            <span style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Search doctor
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Choose your doctor from thousands <br /> of specialist, general,
              and trusted <br /> hospitals.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Online pharmacy
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Buy your medicines with our <br /> mobile application with a
              simple <br /> delivery system.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" /> <br />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Consultation
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Free consultation with our trusted <br /> doctors and get the best
              <br /> recomendations.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Details info
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Free consultation with our trusted <br /> doctors and get the best
              <br /> recomendations.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
            Emergency care
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              You can get 24/7 urgent care for<br /> yourself or your children and your<br />
lovely family.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              Tracking
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              Track and save your medical history<br/> and health data .
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));** to make sure that three elements is equal about width.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div className="row5">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-item">
            
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" alt="searchdoctor" />
            <span style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Search doctor
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Choose your doctor from thousands <br /> of specialist, general,
              and trusted <br /> hospitals.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Online pharmacy
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Buy your medicines with our <br /> mobile application with a
              simple <br /> delivery system.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" /> <br />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Consultation
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Free consultation with our trusted <br /> doctors and get the best
              <br /> recomendations.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              
              Details info
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              
              Free consultation with our trusted <br /> doctors and get the best
              <br /> recomendations.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
            Emergency care
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              You can get 24/7 urgent care for<br /> yourself or your children and your<br />
lovely family.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W3DmpTKH/searchddoctor.png" />
            <span  style=" font-weight: 700; font-size:36px;">
              Tracking
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
              Track and save your medical history<br/> and health data .
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```